# Extracting value from API/Webpage

Tags: rest, web-scraping, google-sheets

I'm trying to retrieve the 'estimated value' field displayed on the `https://www.poppriceguide.com/` website so it can be displayed in a google sheets automatically.
Example URL: `https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/poppriceguide/catalog_items/iron-man-model-39`

I've tried using the `=IMPORTXML()` function as such: 
`=IMPORTXML(https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/poppriceguide/catalog_items/iron-man-model-39, /*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "value", " " ))])`
with no success, seemingly to be caused because it is retrieved using Javascript.

Doing some research I found poppriceguide is using Hobbydb's API which according to Hobbydb should be available.
`https://help.hobbydb.com/support/solutions/articles/36000265069-access-to-the-hobbydb-api`
`https://help.hobbydb.com/support/solutions/articles/36000263216-adding-estimated-values-and-other-data-to-your-own-site`

Going through the network calls I found this API request, however when I do it separately it gives me an authentication failed. 
`https://www.hobbydb.com/api/price_guide?catalog_item_id=520170` 
Other API Requests do work however, for example:
`https://www.hobbydb.com/api/catalog_items/323645`

How would I go about retrieving the value so it can dynamically be displayed in a Google sheets?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `How would I go about retrieving the value so it can dynamically be displayed in a Google sheets?`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of goal?

Answer (score 0):

The link you shared says

> **Let us know if you are interested in exploring co-operation and using the API**. Please provide us with a good overview of your project.

This is likely to mean that the API requires [**authentication**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API)

It is also possible for the API to have certain endpoints that are free, which is why some seem to work. Yet with no publicly available documentation, there is no way to know which ones.

So unfortunately you will not be able to use Apps Script for this, you could look into some other web scraping software, maybe [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer). Or try and apply for an API key from HobbyDB.